# We would like to seat 4 Italians, 3 Germans and 5 Americans in a straight line at a table

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We would like to seat 4 Italians, 3 Germans and 5 Americans in a straight line at a table. How many ways can we do this if:

A) one of the Germans must sit in the first place and the Italians must sit together.

B) not all Americans should sit together.

For question a) i got 4!*8! but i do not know if this is correct. B) question i have no idea how to find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: For B) the simplest way is probably to compute the number of all permutations and subtract the number of permutations in which all Americans do sit together.

Comment: For a), there are $3$ Germans and one of them sits in the first place. So you need to multiply by $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards A), we choose the German for the first place in $3$ ways. Then, for the remaining seats, we permute the $2$ Germans, the $5$ Americans, and the $1$ block of $4$ Italians (to be permuted):
$$3\cdot (2+5+1)!\cdot 4!=3\cdot 8!\cdot 4!$$
So in your answer you forgot to multiply by $3$.

For B), you may evaluate the number of all arrangements without restrictions, that is $(4+3+5)!$, and then take away the number of arrangements where the all $5$ Americans sit together (it's similar to part A)). What is the final result?

Answer (score 2):

For $a)$, your answer should be multiplied by $3$ as the first place should be taken by one of the $3$ Germans.

For $b)$, the answer is $ \ (12! - 8! \cdot 5!)$

as there are $12!$ unrestricted ways of seating all of them and there are $8! \cdot 5! $ ways of seating all Americans together.